# Почему по клику на кнопку download картинка загружается только со второго раза?

Tags: javascript

```js
// Вешаем обработчик события с делегированием для применения фильтров
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let canvasFilter;
const input = document.querySelector('.filters')
  .addEventListener('input', event => {
    if (event.target.matches("input")) {
      const suffix = event.target.dataset.sizing;
      if (event.target.dataset.name === "blur") {
        filter = event.target.dataset.name + "(" + (event.target.value * 2) + suffix + ")";
      } else {
        filter = event.target.dataset.name + "(" + event.target.value + suffix + ")";
      }
      canvasFilter = filter;
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${event.target.name}`, event.target.value + suffix);
    }
  });

// Отображаем значение ползунков в output 
const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
allInputs.forEach(element => {
  const input = element.querySelector(".input");
  const output = element.querySelector(".output");

  input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    setValue(input, output);
  });
  setValue(input, output);
});

function setValue(input, output) {
  const val = input.value;
  output.innerHTML = val;
}

// Настройки для кнопки reset
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const outputs = document.querySelectorAll('output');
let button = document.querySelector('.btn-reset');
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (button.matches(".btn-reset")) {
    inputs.forEach(element => {
      if (element.value) {
        element.value = 0;
        filter = element.name + "(" + element.value + element.sizing + ")";
        canvasFilter = filter;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${element.name}`, element.value);
      }
    });
    outputs.forEach(element => {
      element.innerHTML = 0;
    });
    let saturateOutput = document.getElementById("saturate");
    saturateOutput.innerHTML = 100;
    let saturateInput = document.querySelector(".saturate");
    saturateInput.value = 100;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--saturate`, "100%");
  };
});

// Настройки для кнопки next picture
const base = new Array();
base[0] = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/stage1-tasks/assets/images/night/';
base[1] = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/stage1-tasks/assets/images/morning/';
base[2] = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/stage1-tasks/assets/images/day/';
base[3] = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/stage1-tasks/assets/images/evening/';

const images = ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '05.jpg', '06.jpg', '07.jpg', '08.jpg', '09.jpg', '10.jpg', '11.jpg', '12.jpg', '13.jpg', '14.jpg', '15.jpg', '16.jpg', '17.jpg', '18.jpg', '19.jpg', '20.jpg'];
let i = 0;
let x = 0;
let date = new Date();
let j = date.getHours();
const image = document.querySelector('img');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-next');

function viewImage(src) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = () => {
    image.src = `${src}`;
  };
}

function getImage() {
  i = Math.floor(j / 6);
  const imgIndex = x % images.length;
  const imageSrc = base[i] + images[imgIndex];
  viewImage(imageSrc);
  x++;
  btn.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    btn.disabled = false
  }, 1000);
  return imageSrc;
}
btn.addEventListener('click', getImage);

// Настройки для кнопки Load
const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.img-container');
let currentImg = {};

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = reader.result;
    imageContainer.innerHTML = "";
    imageContainer.append(img);
    currentImg.src = img.src;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

});

// Настройки для кнопки Save picture

const download = document.querySelector('.btn-save');
let currentImage = image;

function drawImage() {
  const img = new Image();
  img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
  if (currentImg.src) {
    console.log(1);
    img.src = currentImg.src;
  } else {
    console.log(2);
    img.src = currentImage.src;
  }

  img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.filter = canvasFilter;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
}

download.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  drawImage();
  console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  let link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'download.png';
  link.href = dataURL;
  link.click();
  link.delete;
});


// Функция на полный экран
function fullscreen() {
  let checkFullScreen = (document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement !== null) ||
    (document.webkitFullscreenElement && document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null);

  let docElement = document.documentElement;
  if (!checkFullScreen) {
    if (docElement.requestFullscreen) {
      docElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (docElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      docElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  user-select: none;
}

a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #313940;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

canvas {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #313940;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #38495a, #a2abb3, #38495a);
}

.header-title {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  padding: 58px 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label:not(.btn) {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-right: 140px;
  color: #a2abb3;
  font-size: 16px;
}

label:hover {
  color: #cbd5de;
}

label:hover output {
  color: #a2abb3;
}

label:active output {
  color: #cbd5de;
}

input[type="range"] {
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #a2abb3;
  margin-top: 22px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #313940;
  border: 3px solid #a2abb3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

label:hover input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}

output {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  right: -80px;
  top: 24px;
  background-color: #454c53;
  border: 1px solid #454c53;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-container>* {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.btn-container>*:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.btn {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #454c53;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn:not(.btn-active):hover {
  background-color: #515961;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}

.btn-active {
  background-color: #00b4a4;
}

.btn-active:hover {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}

.btn-load {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-load--input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filters {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.editor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60%;
}

:root {
  --blur: 0px;
  --invert: 0%;
  --sepia: 0%;
  --saturate: 100%;
  --hue: 0deg;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 520px;
  max-width: 830px;
  object-fit: contain;
  filter: blur(var(--blur, 0px)) invert(var(--invert, 0%)) sepia(var(--sepia, 0%)) saturate(var(--saturate, 100%)) hue-rotate(var(--hue, 0deg));
}

.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 120px;
  right: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-size: contain;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("assets/svg/fullscreen-open.svg");
}

.fullscreen:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

:-webkit-full-screen .fullscreen {
  background-image: url("assets/svg/fullscreen-exit.svg");
}

.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #38495a, #a2abb3, #38495a);
  background-color: #313940;
}

.footer-container {
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.github {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: 45px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  background-image: url("assets/svg/github.svg");
  background-size: 35px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #cbd5de;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.github:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.rss {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 86px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url("assets/svg/rss.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  padding-right: 111px;
}

.rss-year {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  color: #cbd5de;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.rss:hover .rss-year {
  right: -5px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .main {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  label:not(.btn) {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  .btn {
    min-width: 45%;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  .btn-container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
  }
  .btn-container>*:last-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .btn-container>* {
    margin: 10px;
  }
  .main {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .filters,
  .editor {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .fullscreen {
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
  .btn {
    min-width: 145px;
  }
  .btn-container>*:last-child {
    margin-right: 3px;
  }
  .btn-container>* {
    margin: 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
  <link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>photo-filter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="header-title">Photo-filter</h1>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="filters">
      <label class="container">
        Blur:
        <input class="input blur" name="blur" data-sizing="px" data-name="blur" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" />
        <output class="output" name="result">0</output>
      </label>
      <label class="container">
        Invert:
        <input class="input" name="invert" data-sizing="%" data-name="invert" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
        <output class="output" name="result">0</output>
      </label>
      <label class="container">
        Sepia:
        <input class="input" name="sepia" data-sizing="%" data-name="sepia" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
        <output class="output" name="result">0</output>
      </label>
      <label class="container">
        Saturate:
        <input class="input saturate" name="saturate" data-name="saturate" data-sizing="%" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" />
        <output class="output" id="saturate" name="result">100</output>
      </label>
      <label class="container">
        Hue rotate:
        <input class="input" name="hue" data-name = "hue-rotate" data-sizing="deg" type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0" />
        <output class="output" name="result">0</output>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor">
      <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="btn btn-reset">Reset</button>
        <button class="btn btn-next btn-active">Next picture</button>
        <label class="btn btn-load" for="btnInput">
          Load picture
          <input class="btn-load--input" id="btnInput" name="upload" type="file" placeholder="Load picture" />
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-save">Save picture</button>
      </div>
      <div class="img-container">
        <img id="image" src="assets/img/img.jpg" alt="image" />
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>


    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-container">
      <a class="github" href="https://github.com/KseniyaMirosha" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="Open my github page">Kseniya Lazovskaya</a>
      <a class="rss" href="https://rs.school/js/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="Read about the course">
        <span class="rss-year">'21</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <button class="fullscreen openfullscreen" onclick="fullscreen();"></button>

  <script defer src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Всем привет!
Такой вопрос, пишу приложение фото-фильтр, выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Применяю фильтры через канвас, а когда хочу сохранить, то нужная картинка сохраняется только после второго клика, в чем может быть прблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

П.С. Я только учусь, поэтому простите за местами корявый код)

Comment: Оформите вопрос в песосницу

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/KLazosha/xe8k6v0c/2/ вот)

Comment: Тут также есть своя песочница. Оформите сюда. Посмотрите что можно вставить <>

Comment: не могу что-то найти

Comment: Рядом со вставкой картинки. Посмотрите повнимательнее

Comment: все готово) буду очень рада помощи)

Comment: Да конечно посмотрим что к чему

Comment: Ксения если ответ помог разобраться то галочка под стрелками ответа

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так.  Идея проста. Вы рисуете на холст после загрузки картинки. При этом в первый раз сохранение вызывается раньше чем картинка загрузится. Я обернул в таймер для того чтобы картинка успела загрузиться.

```js
// Вешаем обработчик события с делегированием для применения фильтров
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let canvasFilter;
const input = document.querySelector('.filters')
  .addEventListener('input', event => {
    if (event.target.matches("input")) {
      const suffix = event.target.dataset.sizing;
      if (event.target.dataset.name === "blur") {
        filter = event.target.dataset.name + "(" + (event.target.value * 2) + suffix + ")";
      } else {
        filter = event.target.dataset.name + "(" + event.target.value + suffix + ")";
      }
      canvasFilter = filter;
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${event.target.name}`, event.target.value + suffix);
    }
  });

// Отображаем значение ползунков в output 
const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
allInputs.forEach(element => {
  const input = element.querySelector(".input");
  const output = element.querySelector(".output");

  input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    setValue(input, output);
  });
  setValue(input, output);
});

function setValue(input, output) {
  const val = input.value;
  output.innerHTML = val;
}

// Настройки для кнопки reset
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const outputs = document.querySelectorAll('output');
let button = document.querySelector('.btn-reset');
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (button.matches(".btn-reset")) {
    inputs.forEach(element => {
      if (element.value) {
        element.value = 0;
        filter = element.name + "(" + element.value + element.sizing + ")";
        canvasFilter = filter;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${element.name}`, element.value);
      }
    });
    outputs.forEach(element => {
      element.innerHTML = 0;
    });
    let saturateOutput = document.getElementById("saturate");
    saturateOutput.innerHTML = 100;
    let saturateInput = document.querySelector(".saturate");
    saturateInput.value = 100;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--saturate`, "100%");
  };
});

// Настройки для кнопки next picture
const base = new Array();
base[0] = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/stage1-tasks/assets/images/night/';
base[1] = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/stage1-tasks/assets/images/morning/';
base[2] = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/stage1-tasks/assets/images/day/';
base[3] = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/stage1-tasks/assets/images/evening/';

const images = ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '05.jpg', '06.jpg', '07.jpg', '08.jpg', '09.jpg', '10.jpg', '11.jpg', '12.jpg', '13.jpg', '14.jpg', '15.jpg', '16.jpg', '17.jpg', '18.jpg', '19.jpg', '20.jpg'];
let i = 0;
let x = 0;
let date = new Date();
let j = date.getHours();
const image = document.querySelector('img');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-next');

function viewImage(src) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = () => {
    image.src = `${src}`;
  };
}

function getImage() {
  i = Math.floor(j / 6);
  const imgIndex = x % images.length;
  const imageSrc = base[i] + images[imgIndex];
  viewImage(imageSrc);
  x++;
  btn.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    btn.disabled = false
  }, 1000);
  return imageSrc;
}
btn.addEventListener('click', getImage);

// Настройки для кнопки Load
const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.img-container');
let currentImg = {};

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = reader.result;
    imageContainer.innerHTML = "";
    imageContainer.append(img);
    currentImg.src = img.src;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

});

// Настройки для кнопки Save picture

const download = document.querySelector('.btn-save');
let currentImage = image;

function drawImage() {
  const img = new Image();
  img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
  if (currentImg.src) {
    console.log(1);
    img.src = currentImg.src;
  } else {
    console.log(2);
    img.src = currentImage.src;
  }

  img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.filter = canvasFilter;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
}

download.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  drawImage();
  setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  let link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'download.png';
  link.href = dataURL;
  link.click();
  link.delete;},0);
});


// Функция на полный экран
function fullscreen() {
  let checkFullScreen = (document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement !== null) ||
    (document.webkitFullscreenElement && document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null);

  let docElement = document.documentElement;
  if (!checkFullScreen) {
    if (docElement.requestFullscreen) {
      docElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (docElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      docElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  user-select: none;
}

a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #313940;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

canvas {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #313940;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #38495a, #a2abb3, #38495a);
}

.header-title {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  padding: 58px 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label:not(.btn) {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-right: 140px;
  color: #a2abb3;
  font-size: 16px;
}

label:hover {
  color: #cbd5de;
}

label:hover output {
  color: #a2abb3;
}

label:active output {
  color: #cbd5de;
}

input[type="range"] {
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #a2abb3;
  margin-top: 22px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #313940;
  border: 3px solid #a2abb3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

label:hover input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}

output {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  right: -80px;
  top: 24px;
  background-color: #454c53;
  border: 1px solid #454c53;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-container>* {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.btn-container>*:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.btn {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #454c53;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn:not(.btn-active):hover {
  background-color: #515961;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}

.btn-active {
  background-color: #00b4a4;
}

.btn-active:hover {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}

.btn-load {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-load--input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filters {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.editor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60%;
}

:root {
  --blur: 0px;
  --invert: 0%;
  --sepia: 0%;
  --saturate: 100%;
  --hue: 0deg;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 520px;
  max-width: 830px;
  object-fit: contain;
  filter: blur(var(--blur, 0px)) invert(var(--invert, 0%)) sepia(var(--sepia, 0%)) saturate(var(--saturate, 100%)) hue-rotate(var(--hue, 0deg));
}

.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 120px;
  right: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-size: contain;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("assets/svg/fullscreen-open.svg");
}

.fullscreen:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

:-webkit-full-screen .fullscreen {
  background-image: url("assets/svg/fullscreen-exit.svg");
}

.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #38495a, #a2abb3, #38495a);
  background-color: #313940;
}

.footer-container {
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.github {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: 45px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  background-image: url("assets/svg/github.svg");
  background-size: 35px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #cbd5de;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.github:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.rss {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 86px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url("assets/svg/rss.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  padding-right: 111px;
}

.rss-year {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  color: #cbd5de;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.rss:hover .rss-year {
  right: -5px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .main {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  label:not(.btn) {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  .btn {
    min-width: 45%;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  .btn-container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
  }
  .btn-container>*:last-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .btn-container>* {
    margin: 10px;
  }
  .main {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .filters,
  .editor {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .fullscreen {
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
  .btn {
    min-width: 145px;
  }
  .btn-container>*:last-child {
    margin-right: 3px;
  }
  .btn-container>* {
    margin: 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
  <link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>photo-filter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="header-title">Photo-filter</h1>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="filters">
      <label class="container">
        Blur:
        <input class="input blur" name="blur" data-sizing="px" data-name="blur" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" />
        <output class="output" name="result">0</output>
      </label>
      <label class="container">
        Invert:
        <input class="input" name="invert" data-sizing="%" data-name="invert" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
        <output class="output" name="result">0</output>
      </label>
      <label class="container">
        Sepia:
        <input class="input" name="sepia" data-sizing="%" data-name="sepia" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
        <output class="output" name="result">0</output>
      </label>
      <label class="container">
        Saturate:
        <input class="input saturate" name="saturate" data-name="saturate" data-sizing="%" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" />
        <output class="output" id="saturate" name="result">100</output>
      </label>
      <label class="container">
        Hue rotate:
        <input class="input" name="hue" data-name = "hue-rotate" data-sizing="deg" type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0" />
        <output class="output" name="result">0</output>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor">
      <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="btn btn-reset">Reset</button>
        <button class="btn btn-next btn-active">Next picture</button>
        <label class="btn btn-load" for="btnInput">
          Load picture
          <input class="btn-load--input" id="btnInput" name="upload" type="file" placeholder="Load picture" />
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-save">Save picture</button>
      </div>
      <div class="img-container">
        <img id="image" src="assets/img/img.jpg" alt="image" />
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>


    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-container">
      <a class="github" href="https://github.com/KseniyaMirosha" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="Open my github page">Kseniya Lazovskaya</a>
      <a class="rss" href="https://rs.school/js/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="Read about the course">
        <span class="rss-year">'21</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <button class="fullscreen openfullscreen" onclick="fullscreen();"></button>

  <script defer src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает( Я уже без обработчика ставила выполнение функции drawImage(), чтобы сразу на канвасе отрисовывалась картинка, тоже не помогло

Comment: Мне кажется какая-то беда со ссылкой на картинку для канваса

Comment: Странно конечно это очень

Comment: А может ли это быть из-за медленного интернета?

Comment: Чтобы подтвердить теорию просто нарисуйте на канве и сохраните. И потом с загрузкой. Отдельно загрузка отдельно соххранение